# Postfix recipient rewriting from one domain to another

Tags: postfix, rewrite

I have a situation where emails sent to marketing@domain1.com are configured to go to a listserver via virtual_alias_maps:

```
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Data/listserver/aliases/list_server_virtual
```

I also have emails to marketing@domain2.com go there as well, but the listserver sucks (I'm stuck with it), and refuses to accept anything that isn't addressed to domain1.com. So, I thought rewriting might be the solution. Unfortunately, I'm not sure that rewriting ACTUALLY *rewrites* the To: header, which is what I was expecting and what I need to occur (I'm assuming my expectations are flawed).

So, I added:

```
 recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/canonical
```

And /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/canonical contains:

```
 marketing@domain2.com               marketing@domain1.com
```

Now, emails sent to marketing@domain2.com are getting redirected ("rewritten"?) to marketing@domain1.com, but when the email comes through, it still says "To: marketing@domain2.com".

So, to make things easier to troubleshoot, I updated canonical to rewrite marketing@domain2.com to come straight to me (bypassing any potential listserver confusion):

```
 marketing@domain2.com               me@domain1.com
```

But again, when emails are sent to: marketing@domain2.com, they are *correctly* delivered to me@domain1.com, but the headers *still* show "To: marketing@domain2.com"

Is there any way to get Postfix to *literally* rewrite the 'To:' header?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying headers is not recommended and Postfix has abandoned it for reasons explained in [Postfix Address Rewriting](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html):

> Postfix versions 2.1 and earlier always rewrite message header
>   addresses, and append Postfix's own domain information to addresses
>   that Postfix considers incomplete. While rewriting message header
>   addresses is OK for mail with a local origin, it is undesirable for
>   remote mail:
>
> - Message header address rewriting is frowned upon by mail standards,
> - Appending Postfix's own domain produces incorrect results with some incomplete addresses,
> - Appending Postfix's own domain sometimes creates the appearance that spam is sent by local users.
>
> Postfix versions 2.2 give you the option to either not rewrite message
>   headers from remote SMTP clients at all, or to label incomplete
>   addresses in such message headers as invalid.

It's possible to change this behavior for [canonical address mapping](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical):

> NOTE: Postfix versions 2.2 and later rewrite message headers from
>   remote SMTP clients only if the client matches the
>   `local_header_rewrite_clients` parameter, or if the
>   `remote_header_rewrite_domain` configuration parameter specifies a
>   non-empty value. To get the behavior before Postfix 2.2, specify
>
> ```
> local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all
> ```

Also notice that if the headers are DKIM signed, DKIM will fail if tested after rewriting the headers. That's one practical reason why this might not be a good idea.

Comment: I had tried this before posting. I'm running postfix 3.1.1. I have `local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all` in main.cf and I have the mapping as listed above under `recipient_canonical_maps`. It's correctly DELIVERED to the recipient mapped in `recipient_canonical_maps` but the recipient is not modified. The rewritten recipient is nowhere to be found in the headers.

Comment: I found why this didn't work. In master.cf, smtpd had `-o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings` applied. I'll have to figure out why that was on and confirm I can turn it off.

Comment: Good you found a solution. BTW current subversion for this 3.1 legacy release is 3.1.8. Not a huge problem, since Postfix security vulnerabilities are rare.